# Wordpress - display posts in Elementor page using custom field where type is date

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I've tried to implement this, while trying to apply some bits of code taken from here and there.

I'm using Elementor Page Builder in a website and I created a custom post type with ACF. Inside that post type, there's a field for a start_date.

The idea is to only show posts in homepage when the date is equal or higher to present date.

Right now the code is like this:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/por_data', function( $query ) {
// Here we set the query to display posts
// after specific date
$query->set( 'date_query', array(
array(
        'after' => 'May 17, 2020', 
    )
) ); 
} );
```

This obviously just shows posts created after 17 May 2020, which isn't what I want. The idea is to grab the date from that ACF field, compare it with current date and show results accordingly. The custom field type name is "curso"

Found this piece of code but can seem to merge the two together as I have very to little knowledge in programming (yet)

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'events',
'orderby'   => 'event_date',
'meta_key'  => 'event_date',
'order'     => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
  array(
    'key' => 'event_date',
    'value' => date('Y-m-d',time()),
    'compare' => '>'
  )
),
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($q->request);
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to explain it in the comments - hopefully you will get a better understanding of it now.

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/por_data', function( $query ) {

    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
    // Append our meta query instead of overwriting all elementors own metaqueries
    if($meta_query == ""){
        $meta_query = array();
    }
    $meta_query[] = array(
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date', //Or whatever you field is called
            'value' => date('Y-m-d',time()), //Make sure that the format is correct here
            'compare' => '>' //Means that the value should be higher than the key, so this is what you want - If you also need the current dates posts, then you need to use '>=' instead
        )
    );
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query ); //since we appended our query, you can safely set the meta querie now. 
} );
```

You might need to tweak it a little, but this will lead you the right way.

Comment: might actually also need `'relation' => 'AND',` before the array. not sure

Comment: Thanks for the input. Tried to add the code to function.php of the theme, but continues to show all posts, seems not be making the query and comparing it to actual date.
Format is d-m-Y and here's a screenshot of the field: https://prnt.sc/v1as1j